# How to change a color of text and icon within a button whilst hovering over the button?

Tags: html, css, image, button, hover

So far, the code below changes the color of the text and the background whilst hovering. However, the icon will only change while the cursor is hovering over the img. I would like both img and text to change while I hover anywhere in the box.

If this is possible your help will be massively apreciated!

Code I use:

```
HTML
<body>
<a href="#" class='menu-button'>
  <img class="menu-icon" src='https://svgshare.com/i/jLR.svg'> Button</a>
</body>

CSS
.menu-button {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 2em;
  height: 21px;
  color: #72767A;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu-button {
  transition: 0.2s linear;
}

.menu-button:hover {
  background-color: #ffc047;
  border-radius: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

a.menu-button:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

img.menu-icon:hover {
  filter: invert(100%) sepia(100%) saturate(0%) hue-rotate(288deg) brightness(102%) contrast(102%);
}
```

https://codepen.io/harrync92/pen/dymWqoB?editors=1100 [Codepen link for you to play]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the inner element be affected by the :hover of the parent like this:

(I have also added transition to the filter, and generally improved the colors)

```css
body {
  background: #111;
}

.menu-button {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 20%;
  padding: 2em;
  height: 21px;
  gap: 20px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 2px solid white;
  font-size: 20px;
}

img {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

.menu-button {
  transition: 0.2s linear;
}

.menu-button:hover {
  background-color: #ffc047;
  border-radius: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: black;
}

img.menu-icon {
  transition: 0.2s linear;
  filter: invert(100%) sepia(100%) saturate(0%) hue-rotate(288deg) brightness(102%) contrast(102%);
}

.menu-button:hover img.menu-icon {
  filter: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <a href="#" class='menu-button'>
    <img class="menu-icon" src='https://svgshare.com/i/jLR.svg'> Button</a>
</body>
```

Comment: Great, this solved the question. I still haven't grasped parent class mechanics. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: You're welcome. It is *cascading* from up to down (left to right) so `.x .y:hover .z` will affect `.z` when `.y` (which is under `.x`) will be hovered. So for example, you can't have it the other way around: affect parent when child is affected

Answer (score 2):

change

```
img.menu-icon:hover {
  filter: invert(100%) sepia(100%) saturate(0%) hue-rotate(288deg) brightness(102%) contrast(102%);
}
```

to

```
.menu-button:hover img.menu-icon {
  filter: invert(100%) sepia(100%) saturate(0%) hue-rotate(288deg)
    brightness(102%) contrast(102%);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be a case of the ordering of your last class.

Try this:

```
.menu-button:hover .menu-icon {
   filter: invert(100%) sepia(100%) saturate(0%) hue-rotate(288deg) brightness(102%) contrast(102%);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just add

```
.menu-button:hover img{
   filter: invert(100%) sepia(100%) saturate(0%) hue-rotate(288deg) brightness(102%) contrast(102%);
}
```

to your code and it will work just fine.

Here this code indicates that when you will hover on the `.menu-button` class, the color of the img will change.